# How can you fire off a Java action class from a Velocity Template page using struts?

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, struts, velocity

I have a project where I'm trying to get a selected value from a *select* form option and get it into a Java action class.

In my .vm file, I have something like this:

```
<form id="someFormId" name="someFormName" action="someFormAction">
   <select id="someSelectId" name="someSelectName" onChange="someAcion">
      <option>option1</option>
      <option>option2</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Whenever a new select option gets changed, I want to handle that logic in an Java action class, perhaps using struts. Because my current project is a bit larger, I don't want to use JSP files for struts, I just want to be able to reach that action class from my .vm file. Reading the documentation, I haven't found many solid full examples of how to do my xml configurations to include velocity struts and make that action class fire off. Could someone please provide an example of how exactly to map the select change to an action class in velocity templates?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking. When the form is submitted the value of the `<select>` will be sent as part of the request parameters. Are you saying you want to trigger an in-page action on a select change, e.g., an XHR request with a JS handler?

Comment: In your code you use ordinary html on the frontend and you can make a http request from the browser via submitting a form. If you want to handle select box change event you should use JavaScript. Where velocity is used in your code?

Comment: Because of certain complexity reasons, I have to be able to fire off a Java action class. I know that using JavaScript for some actions would be easier, but for the end goal, I do need to fire off a Java function instead. I know this can be done using Apache Struts, but I’m just not sure how because documentation doesn’t provide many examples.

Comment: What does “fire off a Java action class” *mean*? If you want to do something on a *client-side change*, which is what changing a `<select>` does, you have two options: you can make an XHR (Ajax) call, or you can submit the page (which causes a page load). Those are your options. Velocity templates are rendered on the server before anything is sent to the client (e.g., the browser). There is no “calling Java” on the client side other than using JS: web sockets, XHR, normal form posts.

Comment: Because of a way my project is written, I need the select method to send its result to a java class. There is already logic in my java class to work with the backend. I know it isn't as simple as just firing off the java class, but I do know that Apache Struts offers this in some form. In my velocity page, I can add the <select> in a separate frame that will re-render. What I need though, is a way to get that front-end velocity data into my backend java, in the easiest way possible.

Comment: @BennyB If you do not `@` someone in your response nobody knows you've responded. I have told you the two easiest ways to get "Velocity data" (which is meaningless) to the back end from the client.

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you, I didn't know about the @. It isn't meaningless, however. I'm working on a legacy project that requires me to send velocity data to a java action class. I was looking specifically to use Apache Struts, because they offer this capability, but the documentation is poor and I was looking for examples on how to accomplish this in full.

Comment: @BennyB On the client side there's no such thing as "Velocity data" or "front-end Velocity data": Velocity templates are rendered on the server side before anything is sent to the client. **The only way to get data from the client (browser) to the server is via Ajax, a form submission/link/etc, web sockets, etc.**

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand that is the case. Apache Struts are a way of form submission and HTTP requests and such. I'm asking specifically about that, and HOW that is done.

Comment: @BennyB ... I just don't understand. If you're not using Struts now why would you want to introduce Struts just for this? Mapping requests to actions is covered in the Struts 2 documentation, as is basic Struts 2/Velocity integration (although IMO it's not particularly elegant). That said: if you already have a web application I don't understand why you'd bring in S2 just for this--use what you're already using.

Comment: @DaveNewton The application is already using struts. However, it is using struts to submit forms to action classes from JSPs. I am trying to submit form values from velocity template instead, and I'm just unclear as how I can do that.

Comment: @BennyB What is *preventing* you from doing that? The client side doesn't care *how* the DOM is created; if the form `action` property is correct the correct action will be hit. If you're trying to update something based on a select value change, e.g., via Ajax, then the JS needs to retrieve the value from the DOM and hit the back-end endpoint, which has essentially nothing to do with Velocity. You're not explaining what the *problem* is.

Comment: @DaveNewton I guess that might be what I'm asking. If I have my action on my form set to "someAction", and I have a Java Action Class called SomeAction.java, and I have the Struts dependency included, what else am I missing? What is the link between them? I have looked through documentation and it seems very JSP specific, which I don't want. My Java Action class never gets hit either, so I'm just looking for that link between me submitting my form, and the Java Action class getting called, but I need to use struts.

Comment: @BennyB I don't know what you're missing--there's no magic routing from URLs to a Struts 2 action; you need a configuration entry (XML, annotation, etc) for that action--like every other S2 action. This is covered in the S2 documentation and any S2 tutorial.